# Integral $\int\frac{(\ln x)^{10}}{x}\,dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int\frac{(\ln x)^{10}}{x}\,dx$$
All I know is that I am supposed to substitute $u=\ln x$. But can someone please explain to me how to find the anti derivative of $(\ln x)^{10}$. I think we are supposed to use integration by parts on integrating $\ln x$, but we haven't been taught that yet.

Comment: If you take $u = \ln(x)$, what do you get for $du$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Let $u = \ln(x)$, then $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} \implies du = \frac{dx}{x}$

If this is true, what do you see for
$$\int \left(\ln(x)\right)^{10}\left(\frac{dx}{x}\right)$$?

Comment: I'm confused.How did du suddenly equal dx/x?

Comment: I just rearranged some terms. $\frac{\ln(x)^{10}}{x} dx = \ln(x)^{10}\frac{dx}{x}$. I can show more work if you like

Comment: oh thank you! let me try it out!

Comment: Oh I see, this is a common identity, $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x) = \frac1x$

Comment: wait so the derivative of lnx...OH SHOOT HAHAHA i KEPT DOING THE ANTIDERIVATIVE! Thanks for reminding me hahahaha! now let me try